# Making the parent private and the grandparent public for a class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Short story:

is it possible to do

```
class A{};
class B:public virtual A{}; 
class C:public virtual A,private B{};
```

i.e. "showing" that C is an A and not a B, but making it actually a B
without adding the virtual (and the corresponding vptrs)?

Long story:
A has several methods.
B adds some more.
Sometimes I want to forbid the use of one of them. C has this purpose. 
The program has many B, few Cs. I do not want then to make B a subclass of C.

Comment: What is the motivation behind this? Yes, it atleast [compiles](http://codepad.org/JSferQ08), but What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It would be nice to hear the motivation for this, but I don't understand the downvotes etc.

Comment: Thank you @Novelocrat, I added the motivation

Comment: When you find yourself fighting this much with your tools, it's time to change either your tools or your approach.

Comment: It"s possible, but anyone would be able to `dynamic_cast` it to `B`.

Comment: How is it possible to do it without the virtual?

Comment: Real world example. In Qt, there is QSplitter that inherits QWidget. I want my class to be sublcass of QSplitter privately. And I still want it to be QWidget publicly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will do exactly what you intend it to do.
But consider another option: inheriting publicly and hiding the unwanted methods:

```
class A
{
public:
    int a() {return 0xaa;}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    int b() {return 0xbb;}
};

class C: public B
{
private:
    using B::b; // makes the method called b private
};

...
B().b(); // OK, using method b in class B
C().b(); // error: b is private in class C
C().B::b(); // OK: calling b in base-class (not sure if you want to prevent this)
```

This will work with both virtual and non-virtual inheritance.

Comment: thank you. However, yes, I would like to prevent at least the possibility of having
void f(B& b){
  b.b();
}

C c;
f(c);

I can accept the possibility of casting, at least the programmer knows it is doing something potentially dangerous